# Why i should use the NSManagedObjectContext's perform() and performAndWait() while i can use DispatchQueue.global

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, dispatch-queue

I have some confusion about run the CoreData code on the background queue.

There is some methods we can use to perform a CoreData code on the background thread using the NSManagedObjectContext.

```
viewContext.perform { /*some code will run on the background thread*/ }
viewContext.performAndWait{ /*some code will run on the background thread*/ }
```

My question here why i should use these functions rather than using the ordinary way for running some code on the background thread using the DispatchQueue

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { 
     /*some code will run on the background thread*/ 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because **perform** and **performAndWait** guarantee that you will access the objects in the context they were created.

Let's say you have two contexts.

```
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
let mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

By using **perform** or **performAndWait** you guarantee that they are executed in the queue they were created. Otherwise, you will have problems with concurrency.

So you can get the behavior below.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //some code will run on the background thread
        privateContext.perform {
            //some code will run on the private queue
            mainContext.perform {
                //some code will run on the main queue
            }
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, they will all be executed in the background as pointed out in the following code.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //some code will run on the background thread
            do {
                //some code will run on the background thread
                try privateContext.save()
                do {
                    //some code will run on the background thread
                    try mainContext.save()
                } catch {
                    return
                }
            } catch {
                return
            }
        }
```

To get to know more about concurrency, here there is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1) to Apple documentation.